# i am not able to update the label text in tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am trying to update the tkinter label text in a loop.
The text of the label is not updated with the value if `i`.
Below is my code and its output, can anyone help me why is it not working?
Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import messagebox
class Test():
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = tk.Tk()
       self.v = tk.StringVar()
       self.text='yo'
       self.v.set(self.text)
       self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.v.get())
       self.root.after(500,self.callback)
       self.button = tk.Button(self.root,text="RUN Timer",command=lambda:self.runtimer(5))
       self.button.pack()
       self.label.pack()
       self.root.mainloop()
   def runtimer(self,n):
       messagebox.showinfo("information","Information")  
       print(n,' value of n')
       for i in range(0,int(n)):
               print(i)
               self.text=i
               print('value of text',self.text)
               time.sleep(1)
               self.root.after(500,self.callback)
   def callback(self):
       print('in callback')
       print(self.text)
       self.v.set(self.text) 
app=Test()
```

in callback
yo
5  value of n
0
value of text 0
1
value of text 1
2
value of text 2
3
value of text 3
4
value of text 4
in callback
4
in callback
4
in callback
4
in callback
4
in callback
4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you declare the `Label()` tag. `StringVar()` creates an object that can manipulate the text. The `set()` and `get()` method are only used for setting and retrieval of the value. when you call `self.v.get()`, You're getting the value of the StringVar. It's equivalent to setting a static string. To fix this pass `self.v` to the `Label` as `textvariable` instead of setting `self.v.get()` to `text`.

The corrected code would look something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import messagebox
class Test():
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = tk.Tk()
       self.v = tk.StringVar()
       self.text = 'yo'
       self.v.set(self.text)
       self.label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.v)
       self.root.after(500, self.callback)
       self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="RUN Timer", command=lambda:self.runtimer(5))
       self.button.pack()
       self.label.pack()
       self.root.mainloop()

   def runtimer(self, n):
       messagebox.showinfo("information","Information")  
       print(n, 'value of n')
       for i in range(int(n)):
           print(i)
           self.text = i
           print('value of text', self.text)
           self.callback()
           time.sleep(1)

   def callback(self):
       print('in callback')
       print(self.text)
       self.v.set(self.text)
       self.root.update()

app=Test()
```

Comment: The label text is being updated now. But it is only updated with the number 4. I am still getting the same output as before. The callback method is only called when the loop ends. Can u help on that?

Comment: One solution that worked is to directly call `self.callback()` and force the window to update when it's called. I've updated the code to reflect those changes.